VSCode move primary side bar to bottom (*not* the activity bar)
In VSCode, I want to move the primary side bar to the bottom, so that it's easier to use VSCode in a profile-oriented monitor. Is this possible either in the settings or with an extension?
Note that I am not talking about the activity bar. I'm talking about the primary side bar, as described here:

By default, the Primary Side Bar is located on the left of the workbench and shows views such as the Explorer, Search, and Source Control views


I want to use a profile-oriented monitor, but having the sidebar on the side takes up ~1/3 of my screen. It'd be much more economical to have it on the bottom.

you can drag the individual Views to the Panel containing the terminal, that is by default at the bottom, you can hide that bar with Ctrl+B

what is: profile-oriented monitor?

As rioV8 says, you can only achieve what you want by dragging each of the views to the Panel.

@rioV8 thanks! that works well enough for me. If you write it up as an answer I'll happily mark it as the answer

Profile is when the screen's rotated 90 degrees so that it's taller than it is wide. Useful for code if everything's hard wrapped to 80 characters anyway (although lets not start a culture war about line lengths)
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/800x518_smartphone_portrait_vs_landscape_orientation.png

usually that is called Portrait mode opposed to Landscape mode

Ah sorry you're right, my brain was being a little dyslexic it seems

The Views in a View container (Explorer, Search, SCM, Debug, Panel,...) do not have a fixed position.
As shown in the doc about Views you can move them (drag/drop) to a new position in the same View container. But you can also move them to a different View container (mentioned in a release note, I created a doc issue about this not being mentioned in the doc pages, answer: it will be done when the drag/drop is finalized).
A possible new location is the Panel where you have the terminal. And from the Panel you can drag/drop a View to a different View Container in the Primary Side bar.
Following a few links in the issue I found the new doc section about Drag/Drop Views in a doc page about Custom Layout.
If you have no clue where the drop happened or you like to go back to the default positions you can use the command: View: Reset View Locations
